# 4-FSK GnuRadio demodulation

Tags: frequency, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, modulation

I'm trying to demodulate a 4-FSK signal in GnuRadio. I'm a newbie, trying to figure it out myself, but there is little information on this type of modulation. I would be glad to receive any help with my problem. Best wishes.

[graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Cnr.png)
[block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beba2.png)

I converted the signal from complex form to real form without loss of information
Input data - 4-FSK signal with carriers -1944, -648, 648 and 1944 Hz